# What is the read cost of a not found docRef.Get(ctx) in Firestore?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

What is the read cost at point A, B and C? Is it always 1 read no matter what, or are there circumstances under which no read is incurred?

```
dsnap, err := docRef.Get(ctx)
if status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound {
    return nil, ErrNotFound // Point A
}
if err != nil {
    return nil, err // Point B
}

// Point C
```

Comment: For those interested a related question can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640921/what-is-the-read-write-cost-for-firestore-docref-collectionsctx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation on pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#minimum-charge):

> **Minimum charge for queries**
>
> There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you
>   perform, even if the query returns no results.

This suggests that every time you call `Get`, it will cost 1 read if the request hits the server. This is essentially the cost of using the massively scalable Firestore indexes.

Comment: Thanks Doug. That keeps things simple.